# get data from two table(parent-child) mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two Tables:

First Table Data(workflow):

```
workflow_id, name, process_id, branch_id, is_parralel , flow_order
80,          AA,      27,       0,         No,          1
81,            ,      27,       0,         Yes,         2
82,          CC,      27,       0,         No,          3 
83,          BB,      27,       116,       No,          1
84,          DD,      27,       117,       No,          1
85,          EE,      27,       116,       No,          2
```

Second Table data(workflow_parallel_branch):

```
id, workflow_id, branch_name
116,  81,         Branch1
117,  81,         Branch2
```

I want to get data in the below format. How could I make this query?

```
workflow_id,  name
  80,           AA
  83,           BB
  85,           EE
  84,           DD
  82,           CC
```

Comment: The commas in your tables above are very confusing.  It is hard to tell whether this is real data or just a placeholder.

Comment: I for one have no idea what the logic here is. Do you want the rows with no `name`? Or the ones that are not `is_parralel` _(sic)_? Or maybe the ones that do not appear in the `workflow_parallel_branch` table? Any of these could result in your desired output.

Comment: I want to get result in this order 80, 81, 82 where 81 is replaced by the assigned branches 116, 116, 117 and then back to the original order -> 82 as mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess he wants them in the order 80, 81, 82 where 81 is replaced by the assigned branches 116, 116, 117. then back to the original order -> 82

don't know if this is valid in mysql:

```
with workflow (workflow_id, name, branch_id) as                 
(values (80, 'AA', 0), (81, NULL, 0), (82, 'CC', 0),            
        (83, 'BB', 116), (84, 'DD', 117), (85, 'EE', 116)),      
     workflow_parallel_branch (id, workflow_id) as              
(values (116, 81), (117, 81)),                                  
     tmp (id, br, orig, name) as                                
(select  coalesce(b.workflow_id, a.workflow_id), a.branch_id,   
         a.workflow_id, a.name                                  
 from   workflow a                                              
 left   join workflow_parallel_branch b on a.branch_id = b.id   
 order  by a.workflow_id, a.branch_id)                          
select orig, name                                               
from   tmp                                                      
where  name is not null                                         
order  by id,br
```

==>

```
ORIG   NAME
  80    AA 
  83    BB 
  85    EE 
  84    DD 
  82    CC
```

Comment: @PankajKumar No, they just (rather humorously) copy/pasted your comment.

Comment: @user2398621, thx for your answer but this is not execute in mysql.